# Can you assign a pointer of a privately derived class to a pointer of the base class?

Tags: c++

I am reading this (old) book which says that you can explicitly assign a pointer of a privetly derived class to a pointer of that base class. But as I try that example I get an error 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'.

The code is this:

```
class A {};
class B : private A {};

B b, *pb = &b;
A* pa = static_cast<A*>(pb);
```

Comment: Kindly also share the name of the book and page number where it says that.

Comment: What old book is that? The whole deal with private inheritance is that external users of the class that are not declared as friends are not allowed to access anything related to that relationship. That includes the ability to perform static casts. You can probably use `reinterpret_cast`. But that comes with some serious caveats, and is not advisable. I would question why you need to do this in the first place.

Comment: in this schema is a B a kind of A? No, it isn't. the two classes have no relationship to each other, and so neither do pointers.

Comment: @JasonLiam The book is in my native language, which isn't English, so it might be an error by the author ?

Comment: @EdmondDantes You can just copy/paste those exact words and quote them in your question.

Comment: Context matters here. For instance [class B is allowed to perform the cast](https://godbolt.org/z/9WMfzojaW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance declares a relationship between the child class and the parent class, but in the case of private inheritance this relationship is only visible within the child class and its friends. See item 1 of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast:

> 1. If new-type is a reference to some class D and expression is an lvalue of its non-virtual base B, or new-type is a pointer to some complete class D and expression is a prvalue pointer to its non-virtual base B, static_cast performs a downcast. (This downcast is ill-formed if B is ambiguous, inaccessible, or virtual base (or a base of a virtual base) of D.)

The important part of this text is towards the end. A is an "inaccessible" base because at the location in the code where the cast is made, the fact that B inherits from A is not visible. For this reason, the cast in your example is ill-formed which means the compiler must report a compile error on the code.

If you do this static_cast within a method implementation in the B class, the cast will be valid because the base will be accessible.